# Facebook Javascript API ~ Login to Preset Account

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm designing a website in which I want to display pictures from a certain user's Facebook albums. I have the FB Javascript API implemented, but I can't figure out how to login to an account with a predetermined username and password, rather than showing a popup asking the user for credentials.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's with the downvote? I see complete legitimacy in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this via the JavaScript SDK. It's client-side, which would mean you'd basically be giving access to that account to all of your users.

You need to pull this server-side, with an access token for your Facebook user.

Comment: That seems to be what another question indicated as well. Thank you.